# Weird behaviour when mixing loading of assemblies using Assembly.LoadFrom and Assembly.Load

Tags: .net, assemblies, assembly.load

Weird behavior when mixing loading of assemblies using `Assembly.LoadFrom` and `Assembly.Load`:

I have encountered a weird behavior when loading assemblies with `Assembly.LoadFrom` and later on with `Assembly.Load`.
I am loading an assembly using `Assembly.LoadFrom`, where the assembly is located in a folder, which is not the execution folder.

Later on in my test code when I try to load once again this assembly with `Assembly.Load`, the load fails with a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` (“Could not load file or assembly…”) despite the fact that the assembly is already loaded. The load fails both with the strong name and the non-strong name (the original reason for loading once again this assembly is a usage of a `BinaryFormatter`).

However, in case the assembly is located in the execution folder the later load succeeds in both cases, with the strong name and the non-strong name. In this case, you can see that two identical assemblies are loaded from two different locations.

A simple code sample that recreates this problem:

```
Assembly assembly1 = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\a.dll");

// Loading with a strong-name fails
Assembly assembly2 = Assembly.Load(@"a, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=14986c3f172d1c2c");

// Also loading with a non-strong fails
Assembly assembly3 = Assembly.Load(@"a");
```

1. Any explanation why the CLR ignores the already loaded assembly?
2. Any idea how can I alleviate this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not weird. As per the documentation, loading with Load and LoadFrom will place the assemblies in different contexts. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx) might help.

> 1. Any explanation why the CLR ignores the already loaded assembly?

Because they're in a different context.

> 2. Any idea how can I alleviate this problem?

Load from the same context, or help the CLR find the assembly, perhaps by attaching a handler to `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`.

**Alternative**

If the location you are loading assemblies from is a subfolder under AppDomain.BaseDirectory you can simply add an entry to your App.config:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx

Answer (score 7):

@Kent Boogart:
That appears to be the correct explanation. For a full explanation, Suzanne Cook has this blog post which elaborates a little more than the original one you posted:
http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx

Following is code leveraging AppDomain.AssemblyResolve -

```
 // register to listen to all assembly resolving attempts:
 AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
 currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);


 // Check whether the desired assembly is already loaded
 private static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
    Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies) {
       AssemblyName assemblyName = assembly.GetName();
       string desiredAssmebly = args.Name;
       if (assemblyName.FullName == desiredAssmebly) {
           return assembly;
       }
    }

    // Failed to find the desired assembly
    return null;
 }
```